# How to use Pivot Effectively?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pivot

I have following data structure in my WP7 app. And I'm generating three `PivotItems` through databinding, contents of binding. Interesting part is when Binding happens for Pivot items contents(Items) are queried for three time and again selection changes.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="{StaticResource ApplicationName}" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFolder, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="_pivot">
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}}" ItemsSource="{Binding ThingsListViewModel.Items}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

I have three folders items, when Pivot control is created `ThingsListViewModel.Items` property executed thrice, and once every time selection changes.

I'm expecting `ThingsListViewModel.Items` to execute only selection chage on Pivot control.

Comment: You are going to have to give some more detail here. Perhaps post some snippets of your XAML and the code that you are binding to it. What do you mean "Pivote items contents are queried for three time"?

Comment: @ColinE: I think what he means is that each data structure that his PivotItems are bound to are accessed 3 times on each selection change instead of once on each load of that PivotItem. I've never counted how many times this happens but know its more than once because the Pivot loads both PivotItems adjacent to the currently selected item.

Comment: @Praetorian --You're exactly right. If there are only 3 pivots, loading any one, would load the other two; causing any change to trigger 3 queries.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to listen to the LoadedPivotItem and Loaded events of the pivot. The Loaded event will always load the first PivotItem (LoadedPivotItem) will not be called. The LoadedPivotItem is called when the user swipes to another PivotItem.

Based on these events you should then run your queries for the currently SelectedPage. You may also want a flag to indicate once you have loaded the data for each Pivot to avoid running the queries again.